# no matter how puppeteer is installed, runtime gives: `errno: -13 "/.config/puppeteerrc"`

Tags: linux, npm, puppeteer, hadoop-yarn

I've written a couple puppeteer scripts (small ones). In the past, for the first one I wrote, I run into this occasionally:

```
error /var/tmp/vproj/pvid/node_modules/puppeteer: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node install.mjs
Arguments: 
Directory: /var/tmp/vproj/pvid/node_modules/puppeteer
Output:
node:fs:591
  handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
  ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/.config/puppeteerrc'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:591:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:459:35)
    at #readConfiguration (/var/tmp/vproj/pvid/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/ExplorerSync.js:76:39)
    at search (/var/tmp/vproj/pvid/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/ExplorerSync.js:44:63)
    at emplace (/var/tmp/vproj/pvid/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/util.js:12:20)
    at search (/var/tmp/vproj/pvid/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/ExplorerSync.js:64:50)
    at emplace (/var/tmp/vproj/pvid/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/util.js:12:20)
    at search (/var/tmp/vproj/pvid/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/ExplorerSync.js:64:50)
    at emplace (/var/tmp/vproj/pvid/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/util.js:12:20)
    at search (/var/tmp/vproj/pvid/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/ExplorerSync.js:64:50) {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/.config/puppeteerrc'
}

Node.js v19.1.0
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

I heard a suggestion to fix this was to simply uninstall and reinstall puppeteer and that usually would work, but I think is a completely ridiculous thing to have to do. Moreover, I've installed puppeteer both globally and in the project, but I don't run the project in the project directory consistently, which is how I generally run things (from anywhere in the system provided `$PATH` is pointed to the place where the project resides).

I started refactoring another puppeteer script, though, and I'm getting the same error. I've uninstalled and reinstalled both project-level and globally, puppeteer and that doesn't solve the problem. I deleted the package.json file and used yarn instead, as a troubleshooting method.

Do note that all of my permissions are correct. Moreover, it appears that puppeteer is, by default, trying to read `/.config` (root), which doesn't even make sense as I'm not, and have not, run these scripts as root (or any other privileged user). I have a `puppeteerrc.cjs` file in my `$HOME/.config/puppeteer/puppeteerrc.cjs` location as a matter of testing. It was originally in `$HOME/`. Why is puppeteer by default not looking at `$HOME`? It appears to be looking at `/` and that's not a problem as long as it's documented! It's not. Moreover, I have even tried the following within the scripts:

```
/**
 * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
                   // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
                   cacheDirectory: join(process.env['HOME'], '.config', 'puppeteer'),
                 };
```

That doesn't work. Is this a bug in puppeteer? I'm running the latest version.

Here's a minimal set of instructions to reliably repro the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

/**
 * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
                   // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
                   cacheDirectory: join(process.env['HOME'], '.config','puppeteer'),
                 };

(async () =>
{
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
    {
      headless: false,
      args: ['--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required'],
    });
  // ... puppeteer code
  const cookiesString = await fs.readFile('./cookies.json');
  const cookies = JSON.parse(cookiesString);
  await page.setCookie(...cookies);

  let page = await browser.newPage();

  await networkCache.use(page);
})();
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "puppeteer-download",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "downloads images and videos from a website",
  "main": "test.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "kenny harrer",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer-core": "^21.3.6"
  }
}
```

**ADD**

I've created an issue: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/11076

Comment: Please share a minimal script and package.json, along with the commands you're running from other directories where the path fails and OS details so I have everything I need to easily install and run this to [replicate the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen added as an edit.

Comment: Thanks, but ideally pick a URL, don't use `...` and make it easy for me to copy-paste and run the whole project. Did you make changes to this project or is it off-the-shelf? What is the script you're showing? You mention you did refactoring and testing--can you provide all of the relevant code? I have nothing to run to reproduce this problem so there's no way to help.

Comment: I can't provide a URL unfortunately. The URL shouldn't matter, I'd think, as this code isn't even getting to it! I'll add something that reproduces the issue.

Comment: If any URL will suffice, please pick one that isn't sensitive but reproduces the error and hardcode it in. We need to be on the same page with zero non-determinism, running the same script that reproduces the error, to be able to make forward progress. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen I've added reliable repro code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like you did something as root and now you're trying to do something over it as normal user so try it as root or else wipe the folder and do it over as normal user

Comment: @pguardiario I know what it looks like, but I haven't done anything as root. That's what makes this whole thing so confusing.

Comment: @ggorlen any thoughts?

Comment: @Jim - check the permissions and owner of /.config/puppeteerrc also make sure the file isn't locked by another program

Comment: @pguardiario `/.config` doesn't even exist. The problem is that `puppeteer` is trying to read a non existent directory path by drive default. I'm going to open an issue against puppeteer.